# ¿Está obsoleta OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c, opengl

He estado buscando una librería gráfica y encontré OpenGL pero no sé si está obsoleta o no, y no veo tutoriales recientes.

Comment: favor de leer [ask] y checar el [tour], a que te refieres con actualizada? que problemas tiene la versión actual? ya revisaste si su web dice deprecated? además la pregunta no tiene nada que ver con programación y es basada en opiniones por lo ultimo que pides así que es seguro termine cerrada

Comment: `OpenGL` sigue sacando versiones nuevas, la última es la versión **4.6** (14 Junio de 2018).

Answer (score 5):

Viendo el título y las etiquetas de la pregunta entiendo que estás mezclando churras con merinas.

- *C++* es un lenguaje de programación de propósito general. C++ no entiende de tarjetas gráficas, ficheros, sockets, etc.
- [*OpenGL*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL) es una librería multiplataforma que permite *hablar* directamente con la tarjeta gráfica.

Es decir, C++ y OpenGL son elementos que pueden o no ir de la mano. C++ no tiene el beneficio de la exclusividad de *OpenGL*. De hecho, puedes usar OpenGL desde Java, por poner un ejemplo, sin problemas.

En cuanto al uso de *OpenGL*, es una librería que aun está muy viva, aunque [*Vulkan*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulkan) ha nacido para reemplazarla.

Resumiendo, que no encuentres tutoriales nuevos no implica necesariamente que la librería esté en desuso, de hecho la cantidad de tutoriales que realmente merecen la pena se pueden contar con los dedos de la mano. Muchos tutoriales no funcionan o tienen errores o aplican soluciones caseras dificilmente reutilizables.

Piensa, por poner un ejemplo, que tanto la documentación como centenares de tutoriales de la api de Windows han sido históricamente horribles y eso que estamos hablando del SO más extendido en entornos domésticos

Comment: Gracias muy útil